# Using Jquery to switch stylesheets incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles, webfonts

I've been using jquery to switch stylesheets. This is my code:

```
$(function(){

         $(".a").click(function() {
         $("link[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : "/styles/black.css"});
         });

         $(".b").click(function() {
         $("link[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : "/styles/white.css"});
         });

         $(".c").click(function() {
         $("link[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : "/styles/grey.css"});
         });
```

However, when I switch the stylesheets, it  changes the default font. Even though the default font is the same in every stylesheet. The font is supplied by Typekit.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: If you can provide a jsfiddle that would be awesome

Comment: do you import font via javascipt or css?

Comment: You should be able to use Firebug or Inspect Element in Chrome to see where the specified font is coming from (and why it's overidden or not, as the case may be). Right click on an element with the wrong font and go to inspect element and then look at the CSS on the right.

Comment: I think the problem is that he includes the fonts with javascript, when he changes the stylesheet, the css can't recognize the fonts included. The very simple solution is to use css @import method to include fonts.

Comment: I've got the fonts in the css stylesheets.

Comment: @TomJulianHume, can you provide a live link to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:
Place "font-family" in the `<style>` tag in `<head>` and delete it from all style sheets.

You can test `!important` too.